# `NoSuchSessionError: invalid session id` when using selenium, even though application is working fine

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

**Context and info:**

I recently made a simple script that logs into a exterior website and gets some data. The purpose of this script was to get a students grades and then turn it into plottable data. To make the process of getting the data much easier I used the npm library: selenium-webdriver. The reason I used that library instead of request (for example) is because I need to login, and so that I don't get cross origin error (and yes I would get a cross origin error because my server is already connected to a front end app). Note that all of my code is inside an async function and that it is being called like a promise would (meaning that it is being called with a `.then` and not with a `await` inside of an async function.).

**The issue:**

The script works perfectly giving me the exact results I want, but I am still getting an error. This error is confusing to me because of twofold: first because all of my code is in a try block with a catch attached as well as having a `.catch()` where it is called; and second the error is logged after the function has resolved.

**The error message:**

```
(node:17908) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: NoSuchSessionError: invalid session id
 (Driver info: chromedriver=73.0.3683.68 
(47787ec04b6e38e22703e856e101e840b65afe72),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
at Object.checkLegacyResponse (C:\Users\Redacted\Desktop\Application\Code\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:585:15)
at parseHttpResponse (C:\Users\Redacted\Desktop\Application\Code\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:533:13)
at Executor.execute (C:\Users\Redacted\Desktop\Application\Code\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:468:26)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:81:5)
(node:17908) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. 
This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block,
or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:17908) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are 
deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will 
terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

**My code:**

```
'use strict'

const {Builder, By, Key, until,  Capabilities} = require('selenium-webdriver')
const Chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome')

exports.simpleGradebookGetGrades = async function(username, password) {
    const driver = new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').withCapabilities(Capabilities.chrome()).setChromeOptions(new Chrome.Options().addArguments('--remote-debugging-port=25470')).build()
    try {
        let retval = []
        await driver.get('https://simplegradebook.ca/gradebook/login.php')

        async function login(username, password) {
            await driver.findElement(By.name('userid')).sendKeys(username)
            await driver.findElement(By.name('password')).sendKeys(password)
            await driver.findElement(By.name('login')).click()
            await driver.wait(until.titleMatches(/.{20,}/))
            return
        }

        await login(username, password)

        for(let i of Object.keys(await driver.findElements(By.name('viewclasses')))) {
            await driver.wait(until.elementsLocated(By.name('viewclasses')));
            (await driver.findElements(By.name('viewclasses')))[i].click()
            await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.tagName('tbody')))
            retval.push(await driver.findElement(By.tagName('tbody')).getText())
            await driver.get('https://simplegradebook.ca/gradebook/login.php')
            login(username, password)
        }

        return retval
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
    } finally {
        await driver.quit()
    }
}

exports.simpleGradebookGetGrades('Redacted', 'Redacted').then(result => {
    console.log(result)
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
})
```

**My question:**

Why is the error occuring? How can I remove or Ignore this error? Why is my catch block not catching this error?

**Additional info:**

Node version: 11.8.0

Selenium-webdriver version: 4.0.0-alpha.1

Answer (score 1):

Do any of the errors go away if you define your driver with the following option for Chrome?

```
const chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome')
const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver')

let options = new chrome.Options()
let nextPort = 9222 //for example
options.addArguments(["--remote-debugging-port=" + nextPort])
let driver = new webdriver.Builder()
 .withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome())
 .setChromeOptions(options)
 .build()
```

Comment: Can you show the part where you require the library, I don't quite know what is what as I am new to this library. After that i'll accept your answer.

Comment: I think you are just missing `Options` and `Capabilities` from your current selenium imports.  Does it work if you add these to your current import line like this?

`const {Builder, By, Key, Options, Capabilities, until} = require('selenium-webdriver')`

Comment: Same errors occur?  Also, could you possibly edit into your question the code you have added?

Comment: @ C. Peck Yes, it still does.

Comment: Thanks for updating the question.  I don't see where you added `options.addArguments(["--remote-debugging-port=" + nextPort])
` to your chrome options.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @ C. Peck I didn't see where nextPort was defined, if you could tell me where that is then I could try it.

Comment: I meant for it to be defined right before 

`options.addArguments(["--remote-debugging-port=" + nextPort])`

but forgot what language I was working in.  Is my edit better?

Comment: @ C. Peck Unfortunately, it still does not work. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: You can use any port number that you have available, the whole point is just to send the debugging info to someplace else so that you don't get these errors when all the tests pass.

Comment: @ C. Peck Yes, still the same one

Comment: Only thing I can think of is you need to specify a port that you have open.  If that doesn't work I think I'm out of ideas and someone smarter than me will have to help you.

Comment: @ C. Peck Ok, that's too bad. Still you were very helpful.